# Why does dropdown list selection from a location hash work on Chrome, but not Firefox, IE, or Safari?

Tags: javascript, url, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

Complete JS novice. I want a "Request A Quote" button to auto-populate a dropdown menu on a new page based on the product and url.  Each product quote button links to the same form but with a different hash value in the url which matches an option in the dropdown menu.

Example:

1. User clicks "Request A Quote" for 'Product A'
2. User is sent to `www.example.com/request-a-quote/#Product A`
3. Product dropdown menu (`id=product-select`) on form already reads "Product A"

This code works on Chrome, but not for anything else. What am I doing wrong?

```
//Get select object
var objSelect = document.getElementById("product-select");
var val = window.location.hash.substr(1);

//Set selected
setSelectedValue(objSelect, val)

function setSelectedValue(selectObj, valueToSet) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
        if (selectObj.options[i].text== valueToSet) {
            selectObj.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `works on Chrome, but not for anything else` - look in the bowsers developer tools console for any errors. My guess is `objSelect` is undefined, and you'll have an error on the for loop line

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code.... The option tag officially supports the value attribute vs text which is the user readable name.  We use value as an identifier:

```
selectObj.options[i].value == valueToSelect;
```

You will also need to change the select.options markup to use the value attribute rather then text.

**UPDATE more info as requested:**

The purpose of `text` is to provide a user readable option.  We use `value` to identify the selection to the server and in your case the URL hash.  By using the `value` attribute, you can use URL safe values and user readable text.

The fix you posted in your answer is really bad practice and will become problematic as the complexity of your code increases.

This example will work in all browsers and is the proper way to implement.

```js
//Simulate hash
window.location.hash = '2'
var val = window.location.hash.substr(1);

var selectEle = document.getElementById('select')
setSelectedValue(selectEle, val)

function setSelectedValue(selectObj, valueToSet) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
     var selection = selectObj.options[i]
        if (selection.value == valueToSet) {
            selection.selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<select name="selections" id="select">
  <option value="1">Product A</option>
  <option value="2">Product B</option>
  <option value="3">Product C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Changing to .value made it start working on IE, but it still does not work on Firefox and Safari.

@arctelix what did you mean by - You will also need to change the select.options markup to use the value attribute rather then text.

Comment: Ah! I found that one word strings after the hash work on Firefox and Safari, meaning the spaces are messing up the window.location.hash.substr(1); when storing that value.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found that applying decodeURIComponent() cleaned up my val variable.

Also, building links as www.example.com/request-a-quote/#Product A is important.  If the forward slash is not before the hash, mobile Safari will ignore everything after the hash and it won't work.

Below is my final solution:

```
//Get select object
var objSelect = document.getElementById("product-select");
var val = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash.substr(1));

//Set selected
setSelectedValue(objSelect, val)

function setSelectedValue(selectObj, valueToSet) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
        if (selectObj.options[i].text== valueToSet) {
            selectObj.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: YIKES, please don't do that!  See my updated answer for more info and the proper way to implement this. @AMAC71